# Preventing a decompiler to disclose the links used in Android app

Tags: java, android

I have been working on an application for 1 month and now it is completed.
I have used some backend code in PHP.

In my app i have used the link of those PHP files.
Now as the reverse engineering of an APK file ( using Dex2Jar ) reveals all codes, my links won't be safe.

All i want is to prevent those links to be seen by any one who tries to decompile the APK.

**Is there a way to encode those links so it wont be readable after decompiling? or any other alternate solution?**

Thanks....

Comment: Actually no point of hiding the links because somebody can actually sniff the url using some tool like Wireshark etc.

Comment: "Is there a way ...": no, not really. The best you can do is to obfuscate them a bit. But any serious attacker can reveal them.

Comment: will you please provide any idea about obfuscating them?